# nest SELECT in INSERT

Tags: mysql, insert

I'm trying to do something like:

```
INSERT INTO stories 
   (vid, ip, body, timestamp) 
VALUES (
   (SELECT vid+1 FROM stories ORDER BY vid DESC LIMIT 1), 
   INET_ATON('127.0.0.1'), 
   'test', 
   NOW()
)
```

but I'm having a problem figuring out how to nest a SELECT statement's returned data into an INSERT statement. I need to figure out how to get the highest existing vid and increment it by 1.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use an explicit SELECT, not nested

```
INSERT INTO stories 
   (vid, ip, body, timestamp) 
SELECT
   COALESCE(MAX(vid),0)+1,    --max always returns one row if no group by
   INET_ATON('127.0.0.1'), 
   'test', 
   NOW()
FROM stories
ORDER BY vid DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: that's a great solution! thank you. one more thing though - how do I return an integer 1 for vid value if table stories is empty?

Comment: @Donkapone ~ That sounds like "I have two different business cases, I should test for one of them to be valid, and then execute one of two different paths depending on that test result" doesn't it? How would you solve it?